# Sql Link 3 Tables but still show unique of 1 of them

Tags: sql

I'm trying to link 3 tables using inner join but there is something in each one which needs to be searchable so unsure how to do this in 1 statement.

Should I use inner joins or group by or union or am I completely off track ?

Example:

Tables:

```
Table 1 customerid , customername , customerpostcode

table 2 customerid , customerorderid , customeritemordered , SKU (these table will have multiple entries for 1 order.

table 3 productid , SKU
```

Relationships:

```
table1 > table2  linked by customerid

table2 > table3  linked by sku
```

Customer orders 3 items , will be 1 entry in table1 , 3 entries in table2 , table3 is simply linked to the actual product names etc.

So I only want it to show me 1 line of results from table1

What is best method to achieve this , or is my logic completely wrong ?

Comment: is this MySQL or some other DBMS? Please clarify.

Comment: Also please give an example of the kind of thing you mean by "searchable"? You want a WHERE clause which references fields from another table? What are the exact fields and the criteria?

Comment: The WHERE statement might be where customername = ? (from table1) OR Sku = ? (from table2) OR productTitle= ? (from table3)   and then show the 1 line so it is showing unique order from table1    but not sure if this even logically works , basically i need to search all 3 tables but be able to show a single line result as in table1 details.

Comment: sorry yes i was using pdo prepare.

Comment: " i was using pdo prepare"...doesn't tell me if it's mysql or something else. PDO can be used to access several different DB engines

Comment: "where customername = ? (from table1) OR Sku = ? (from table2) OR productTitle= ? (from table3)" using this query you can't guarantee to get one single result. The same SKU could be on multiple orders, for instance, so you'd get multiple results, not a single line.

Comment: Yeh i use mariadb so mysql i think you call that , still a novice :P     yes you are corect my logic is trying to do too many things     if searching order customername from table1 wanted to show 1 line only whihc is guranteed , but if searching SKu wanted to show all orders that use that SKU , but if searching productname wanted to show all orders with that product name , so yeh i think i am trying to do 2 different things so not sure if its even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN
table2 AS t2 ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid INNER JOIN
table3 AS t3 ON t2.SKU = t3.SKU 
WHERE (t1.customerid = @searchId OR t3.SKU = @searchSKU OR t2.customerId = searchCustomerId)
LIMIT 1
```

The LIMIT 1 statement in the will ensure you'll only receive maximum one line as a result.

Comment: Yeh i had it working like this already , but only want the results from table1 , so even if there is 3 lines in table2 i only want it to show the 1 line.     reason to access all in the 3 tables is say table2 has 3 products ordered i am using that in part of the search query above in the where statement.     ie where SKU = 123   but i need all 3 tables searchable   from table1 may search customername , table2 may search Sku , table 3 may search the product title.

Comment: So what is your search criteria to define which of the 3 rows of table2 you want to show?

Comment: When you search for a customer, how do you define which of the n products linked to this customer (table2 -> table1) you want to show?

Comment: I updated my answer to only show one result maximum (MSSQL syntax)

Comment: yeh its confused me and was not even sure i was going about it the right way , my mariodb does not seem to like top 1 , am i doing something wrong or is there a different statement ?

Comment: Yes i think its my logci failing as i had not thought about what ones would take priority searching table2 , Limit will limit the entire thing so only ever 1 result , ie same as if i search by productname which is in table3 i wanted to show result for reach 1 but only the 1 order,  i think i have to re-think it through what i am trying to achieve , your answers are correct but my logic is trying to do too many things :P